# how to display none through code behind

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have tried this

```
login_div.Style("display") = "none";
```

But it's not working.how can I set the display of the div to none through code behind,
in aspx I have a div:

```
<div id="login_div" runat="server">
```

Comment: If you set the css to `display: none;` then it won't display. I don't understand what your asking.

Comment: @earlz: It won't display *initially*, but it can be changed with Javascript.

Comment: actually i want to do it in codebehind file

Comment: why do you want to do this in code behind? Could you better explain the situation?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
login_div.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
```

Answer (score 14):

Try if this works:

```
Panel2.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

`<div id="login_div" runat="server">`

and on the code behind.

`login_div.Style.Add("display", "none");`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(displayit){
  login_div.Style["display"]="inline"; //the default display mode
}else{
  login_div.Style["display"]="none";
}
```

Adding this code into `Page_Load` should work. (if doing it at Page_Init you'll have to contend with viewstate changing what you put in it)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a login div, shouldn't the default be to NOT display it. I am going to go ahead and assume then you want to display it then via javascript.

```
<div id="login" style="display:none;">Content</div>
```

Then using jQuery:

```
<script type="javascript">$('#login').show();</script>
```

Another method you might consider is something like this:

```
<div id="login" style="display:<%=SetDisplay() %>">Content</div>
```

And the SetDisplay() method output "none" or "block"

Answer (score 0):

```
div_id.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
```

**div_id**: id which you want to hide.

**Attributes**: that will use value.

**Add**: keyword will add the attribute.

**Style**: is the attribute.

and last one is the name and value of the attribute